# Write for loop to perform a calculation on a specific amount of rows from existing dataframe column and append that calculation into a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am attempting to calculate a 10 year forward return from historical stock data. I have a dataframe:

```
    import blpapi
    options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    options.setServerHost('localhost')
    options.setServerPort(8194)
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal
    import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm


    # data manager
    mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()

    # Bloomberg variables
    px = 'PX_LAST'

    # start and end date
    start_dt = '1952-01-01'
    end_dt = date.today()

    # tickers
    mve_tick = 'NCBEILQ027S' # Fred
    gdp_tick = 'GDP' # Fred
    sp_tick = mgr['SPX INDEX'] # Bloomberg

    # get data
    mve = fred.get_series(mve_tick, observation_start = start_dt, 
    observation_end = end_dt)
    gdp = fred.get_series(gdp_tick, observation_start = start_dt, 
    observation_end = end_dt)
    sp = sp_tick.get_historical(px, start_dt, end_dt)

    # create data frames
    mve_df = pd.DataFrame(mve)
    mve_df.index.name = 'Date'
    mve_df.columns = ['MVE']
    gdp_df = pd.DataFrame(gdp) * 1000
    gdp_df.index.name = 'Date'
    gdp_df.columns = ['GDP']
    gdp_col = gdp_df['GDP']
    sp_df = pd.DataFrame(sp)
    sp_df.index.name = 'Date'
    sp_df.columns = ['Price']

    # convert S&P to quarterly return
    sp_df = sp_df.resample('3MS').first()
    sp_df_col = sp_df['Price']

    # merge data frames
    df = mve_df.join([gdp_col, sp_df_col])
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
    df['Q Return'] = df['Price'].pct_change()
```

I want to append a new column based on a calculation run on the 'Q Return' column.

I want to multiply the values of the first 40 data points in col 'Q Return' and then raise that sumproduct to (4/40) and have that be the first value in my new appended column. Then the next value will be the sumproduct of rows 1-41 of column 'Q return' and then raise that to same exponent and so on.

I wrote this function to perform the calculation:

```
    def fwdreturn(returns, t):
        outp = 1
        for i in range(t, t + 40):
            outp = outp * i
        return outp'
    df['10 Year Fwd Return'] = [fwdreturn(df['Q Return'], t) for t in df['Q Return']] # this is where error is occuring
    print(df)
```

The error I am getting is 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: thanks for the feedback - I edited trying to make it look better ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but that error is happening because you're passing in each value in your column to your function as `t`, and then trying to use that float value as the parameters of `range` (which must be integers)

if you're trying to multiply each value in the column by the next 40 values in the column, maybe something like this:

```
def fwdreturn(returns, start_index):
    outp = 1
    for i in range(0, 40):
        outp = outp * returns[start_index + i]
    return outp
df['10 Year Fwd Return'] = [fwdreturn(df['Q Return'].to_list(), idx) for idx in range(0, df['Q Return'].size)]
print(df)
```

HOWEVER this is going to run into a huge problem when you get to the point where there are fewer than 40 subsequent values to multiply by. You'll have to figure out what you want the result to be at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - so i had changed my code to something similar to what you answered, and now I am getting KeyError: 269 (269 is number of rows in the df) .. when I run your code as well, I get the same error...

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was mentioning in my HOWEVER up there. It's getting to the point where there aren't 40 subsequent values to multiply together and erroring out. What behavior would you expect in that scenario? Just multiply together the next 39?

Comment: So I don't need that data - because im just trying to show historic 10 year forward returns for the s&p 500.. so how could write the code so once it gets to the point there is not 40 rows left it just says NaN or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this:

```
    def fwdreturn(returns, t):
        outp = 1
        for i in range(t, t + 40):
            try:
                outp = outp * df['Q Return'][i]
            except KeyError:
                    return np.nan
        return outp

    df['10 Year Fwd Return'] = [fwdreturn(df['Q Return'], t) for t in df.index]


    print(df)
```